# Autoform: variable is not in the window scope

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I am trying to display an autoform on the main page of the website by attaching a schema to it.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Inventory is not in the window scope

**`server.js`**:

```js
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

Inventory = new Mongo.Collection('inventory');
Inventory.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    customTonerName: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Custom Toner'
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        label: 'Quantity'
    }
}));
```

**Main template**:

```html
{{#autoForm collection="Inventory" id="insertInventoryForm" type="insert"}}
    {{> afQuickField name='quantity'}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: With quotes, `collection="Inventory"`, means "look for `window.Inventory`" whereas without quotes, `collection=Inventory`, means "look for a `helper` or `property` or `variable` in current scope with the name Inventory"

Answer (score 2):

Providing you the 2 solutions for this in the order od recommendation.

> **Solution No. 1** : Just make a simple helper function in `.js` file as below,

**Main.js**

```
import { Inventory } from 'your location'; // mention path here

Template.Main.helpers({  
  Inventory(){
    return Inventory;
  }
});
```

**Main.html**

```
{{#autoForm collection=Inventory id="insertInventoryForm" type="insert"}}
    {{> afQuickField name='quantity'}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

> **Solution No.2** : Import your collections on a Main.js client file and add them to the window scope.

**Main.js**

```
import { Inventory } from 'your location'; // mention path here

window.Inventory = Inventory;
```

**Main.html**

```
{{#autoForm collection="Inventory" id="insertInventoryForm" type="insert"}}
    {{> afQuickField name='quantity'}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

> **Note**: For more insight on this , [click here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/1449)